# Convert time AM and PM TO 24 hour format

Tags: flutter

```
String timer = "01:30 PM"
String  = "12/10/2020"
DateTime fdate = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(dates);
DateTime ftime = DateFormat("hh:mm:ss").parse(timer);
```

I am getting the error while converting the string time into the Original time format. How to convert that time and date into the different format.

How to get the combination of date and time like 2020-10-12 13:30:00

Answer (score 3):

Change ftime to :

```
DateTime ftime = DateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(timer);
```

Consider reading [DateFormat Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html) for more information

Comment: thanks bro..it took me one day sorting this....